# How to fork a Linux process in a Stopped state?

Tags: linux, fork, clone, system-calls

I am starting a new task using a `clone(2)` call.

There used to be `CLONE_STOPPED` flag, but it is no longer present in current kernel.

Is there any trick to start a task in a Stopped state (waiting for `SIGCONT` to actually run)?

Comment: What is your purpose in doing this? If this is for debugging purposes you might be able to use `ptrace` with `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`

Comment: Because the API I am implementing requires that `spawn_thread()` spawns thread in stopped state, waiting for `resume_thread()`. I didn't design it - I'm just implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, there's no way to do that in recent kernels, not unless you write a kernel module to do that.

You can see how kernel v2.6.32 used to do it in [kernel/fork.c (L1449)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c?v=2.6.32#L1449):

```
if (unlikely(clone_flags & CLONE_STOPPED)) {
    /*
     * We'll start up with an immediate SIGSTOP.
     */
     sigaddset(&p->pending.signal, SIGSTOP);
     set_tsk_thread_flag(p, TIF_SIGPENDING);
    __set_task_state(p, TASK_STOPPED);
} else {
    wake_up_new_task(p, clone_flags);
}
```

It should be possible (but arguably not trivial?) to write a wrapper function in kernel space to do something similar.

Comment: Well... Forwardporting that code is one option I am considering too. Thanks for nailing it for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The child can send itself `SIGSTOP` at the beginning of the executed `fn`

Comment: This is what I ended up doing so far, but this is not exactly what the question is about. :-)
There are issues with other processes racing to STOP/CONT it if it is initially Running just to Stop itself.

Comment: Also, it turns out that SIGSTOP is a process-level handled signal, so while it is possible to SIGCONT a task, SIGSTOP will stop the whole task group.