# Is it possible to start a linux process, getting the PID, but start running later on certain condition?

Tags: linux

I'm thinking about some tool that can pause the program at start.

For example, `my_bin` starts running at once.

```
$ ./my_bin
```

With this tool

```
$ magic_tool ./my_bin
```

`my_bin` will start.  I can get the `PID`.  Then I can start the actual running later.

Comment: Can you provide more info about  purpose / use case?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959016/how-to-fork-a-linux-process-in-a-stopped-state

Comment: @igr Just curiosity

Comment: Start a process, `fork`, save child's pid somewhere, have child send `SIGSTOP` to itself before it calls `execve` with `my_bin`, parent exits, resume later with `SIGCONT` to the child. Am I missing something? (genuine question, not sure if this would work)

Comment: I'm curious about why you think this can be useful; why would one need such a tool?

Comment: so not just a wrapper for a `sleep` command to precede launching the real program? Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just tested my suggestion in the comments and it worked! This is the code in my `magic_tool.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid; 
        
    printf("Executing %s to wrap %s.\n", argv[0], argv[1]);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
        return -1;
        
    if (pid == 0) {
        raise(SIGSTOP);
        execl(argv[1], "", NULL);
    } else {
        printf("PID == %d\n", pid);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote another test program `target.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    puts("It works!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Running `./magic_tool ./target` printed a PID and returned to shell. Only after running `kill -SIGCONT <printed_pid>` was `It works!` printed. You'll probably want to have PID saved somewhere else and also perform some checks in the `magic_tool`, but I think this is nonetheless a good proof of concept.

**EDIT:**

I was playing around with this a bit more and for some reason it didn't always work (see why below). The solution is simple - just follow a proper [fork off and die](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Fork_off_and_die) pattern a bit more closely in `magic_tool.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid; 

    printf("Executing %s to wrap %s.\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
        return -1;

    if (pid == 0) {
        setsid();
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)
            return -1;

        if (pid == 0) {
            raise(SIGSTOP);
            if (execl(argv[1], "", NULL))
                return -1;
        }       
        printf("PID == %d\n", pid); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I found an explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065170/12062404):

> When you start the root process from your shell, it is a process group leader, and its descendants are members of that group. When that leader terminates, the process group is orphaned. When the system detects a newly-orphaned process group in which any member is stopped, then every member of the process group is sent a SIGHUP followed by a SIGCONT.
>
> So, some of your descendant processes are still stopped when the leader terminates, and thus everyone receives a SIGHUP followed by a SIGCONT, which for practical purposes mean they die of SIGHUP.
>
> Exactly which descendants are still stopped (or even just merrily advancing toward exit()) is a timing race.

The answer also links to [IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 _Exit entry](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html) which contains more details on the matter.

Answer (score 4):

This is mostly a very similar idea as @gst, but done entirely in the shell, you can spawn a subshell (this forks and create a new pid) and have the subshell send itself SIGSTOP signal, when the subshell receives a SIGCONT signal and resumes, the subshell `exec` the intended program (this replaces the subshell with the intended program without creating a new pid). So that the main shell can continue doing stuff, the subshell should run on background with `&`.

In a nutshell:

```
(kill -STOP $BASHPID && exec ./my_bin) &
subpid=$!    # get the pid of above subshell
... do something else ...
kill -CONT $subpid   # resume
```

---

Another idea that wouldn't suffer from race condition between the main process sending SIGCONT and the subshell SIGSTOP-ing itself is to use a file descriptor to implement the wait instead:

```
exec {PIPEFD}<> <(:)   # set PIPEFD to the file descriptor of an anonymous pipe
(read -u $PIPEFD && exec ./my_bin) &
subpid=$!    # get the pid of above subshell
... do something else ...
echo >&$PIPEFD    # resume
```